# Element by element comparison in tuple to return set of sets - python

Tags: python

I am new to python. Someone help me with this requirement. I have a data set with attributes in the first row and the records in the remaining rows.

My requirement is to compare each record with other record and give the attribute name of the elements which are different. So at the end, I should have set of sets as output.

For example, if i have 3 records with 3 columns like this.

```
         Col1 Col2 Col3
tuple1    H   C    G
tuple2    H   M    G
tuple3    L   M    S
```

It should give me like this tuple1,tuple2 = {Col2} tuple1,tuple3 = {Col1,Col2,Col3} tuple2,tuple3 = {Col1,Col3}

And the final output should be {{Col2},{Col1,Col2,Col3},{Col1,Col3}}

Here is the code which i have tried,

What i did now is, reading each row in to a list. So all the attributes in one list(list name is list_attr) and rows as list of lists(list name is rows). Then for each record, i am looping with other records, comparing each element and getting the index of the different element to get attribute name. And then finally converting them to set. I have given the Code below, but the problem is, I have 50k records and 15 attributes to process, so this looping takes long time to execute, is there any other way to get this done soon or improve the performance.

```
dis_sets = []  
for l in rows:
    for l1 in rows:
        if l != l1:
            i = 0
            in_sets = []
            while(i < length):
                if l[i] != l1[i]:
                    in_sets.append(list_attr[i])
                i = i+1
            if in_sets != []:
                dis_sets.append(in_sets)
skt = set(frozenset(temp) for temp in dis_sets)
```

Comment: It looks like you understand the requirements write well. Now try to code a solution, and when you'll run into a problem you can't solve, a bug you can't figure etc - post it here.

Comment: I tried to code it and ended up writing repeated for loops and so it is taking time, so looking for better alternatives from others..

Comment: Try to write an algorithm (steps) required to solve the problem. Then write a function for each step. After each step works fine separately, try to combine the steps into a workflow: call each step, in order, from a main function. Trying to "swallow" all the login into one gigantic function/logic is bad for reading, debugging, testing and maintaining (as you've already experienced).

Comment: Alfasin, thanks for your reply and i did that.. Here is my code updated now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
>>> tuple1=('H', 'C', 'G')
>>> tuple2=('H', 'M', 'G')
>>> tuple3=('L', 'M', 'S')
```

OK, you state 'My requirement is to compare each record with other record and give the attribute name of the elements which are different.'

Put that into code:

```
>>> [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(tuple1, tuple2), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]]
[2]
>>> [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(tuple1, tuple3), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(tuple2, tuple3), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]]
[1, 3]
```

Then you state 'And the final output should be `{{Col2},{Col1,Col2,Col3},{Col1,Col3}}`

Since a set of sets will loose order, this does not make sense. It should be:

```
>>> [[i for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]] for pair in 
...     [(tuple1, tuple2), (tuple1, tuple3), (tuple2, tuple3)]]
[[2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

If you *really* want sets, you can have them as the sub element; if you have a true set of sets you have lost the information of which pair is which.

List of sets:

```
>>> [{i for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]} for pair in 
...     [(tuple1, tuple2), (tuple1, tuple3), (tuple2, tuple3)]]
[set([2]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 3])]
```

And your *almost* same desired output:

```
>>> [{'Col{}'.format(i) for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]} for pair in 
...     [(tuple1, tuple2), (tuple1, tuple3), (tuple2, tuple3)]]
[set(['Col2']), set(['Col2', 'Col3', 'Col1']), set(['Col3', 'Col1'])]
```

(Note that since sets are unordered, the order of the strings changes. If the top level order changes, what do you have?)

Notice if you have a list of lists, you are closer to you desired output:

```
>>> [['Col{}'.format(i) for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]] for pair 
...     in [(tuple1, tuple2), (tuple1, tuple3), (tuple2, tuple3)]]
[['Col2'], ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], ['Col1', 'Col3']]
```

---

*Edit based on comment*

You could do something similar to:

```
def pairs(LoT):
                   # for production code, consider using a deque of tuples...
    seen=set()     # hold the pair combinations seen
    while LoT:
        f=LoT.pop(0)
        for e in LoT:
            se=frozenset([f, e])
            if se not in seen:
                seen.add(se)
                yield se

 >>> list(pairs([('H', 'C', 'G'), ('H', 'M', 'G'), ('L', 'M', 'S')]))
 [frozenset([('H', 'M', 'G'), ('H', 'C', 'G')]), frozenset([('L', 'M', 'S'), ('H', 'C', 'G')]), frozenset([('H', 'M', 'G'), ('L', 'M', 'S')])]
```

Which then can be used thus:

```
>>> LoT=[('H', 'C', 'G'), ('H', 'M', 'G'), ('L', 'M', 'S')]
>>> [['Col{}'.format(i) for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair), 1) if t[0]!=t[1]] for pair 
...        in pairs(LoT)]
[['Col2'], ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], ['Col1', 'Col3']]
```

---

*Edit #2*

If you want a header vs a calculated value:

```
>>> theader=['tuple col 1', 'col 2', 'the third' ]
>>> [[theader[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]] for pair
...       in pairs(LoT)]
[['col 2'], ['tuple col 1', 'col 2', 'the third'], ['tuple col 1', 'the third']]
```

If you want (what I suspect the the *right* answer) a List of Dicts of Lists:

```
>>> di=[]
>>> for pair in pairs(LoT):    
...    di.append({repr(list(pair)): [theader[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]]})
>>> di
[{"[('H', 'M', 'G'), ('H', 'C', 'G')]": ['col 2']}, {"[('L', 'M', 'S'), ('H', 'C', 'G')]": ['tuple col 1', 'col 2', 'the third']}, {"[('H', 'M', 'G'), ('L', 'M', 'S')]": ['tuple col 1', 'the third']}]
```

Or, just a straight Dict of Lists:

```
>>> di={}
>>> for pair in pairs(LoT):    
...    di[repr(list(pair))]=[theader[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]]  
>>> di
{"[('H', 'M', 'G'), ('L', 'M', 'S')]": ['tuple col 1', 'the third'], "[('L', 'M', 'S'), ('H', 'C', 'G')]": ['tuple col 1', 'col 2', 'the third'], "[('H', 'M', 'G'), ('H', 'C', 'G')]": ['col 2']}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. But i need to compare each tuple with all other tuples, totally i have 50k tuples. And so its literally not possible to give like this [(tuple1, tuple2), (tuple1, tuple3), (tuple2, tuple3) i guess. And i dont need to return the different element as output set, i need to return the column name of the different element as set, so i thought of using the index of the different element and get the column(attribute) from attribute list(which is here list_attr). Could you please help to make use of this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again. It seems perfect. But i need to use the column names instead of the values in the list. First row of the dataset will have the column names. For example if the column names of (H,C,G) are employee, dept, Mgr. Then, I need to return the same.

Comment: I think you can take it from here. ;-)  If you have a problem ask a new question. `zip` is your friend

Comment: Thanks my friend.. Got you.. :-)

Comment: Hi. I tried the code given. With def pairs(LoT) function and then this code skt = set(frozenset([list_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]]) for pair in pairs(rows)). I am stuck with Memory error --  skt = set(frozenset([list_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]]) for pair in pairs(rows))
  File "C:*******Rough.py", line 139, in pairs
    seen.add(se)
MemoryError

Comment: @dawg: why is `seen` a global, outside of `pairs` here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Because I made a mistake -- used to be `pairs` was not a function or a generator. I will fix.

Comment: @Jeeva: My guess is you are running low on memory with 50K tuples and the associated data here. You will either need to do it in pieces (pickling portions to disk as you go) or come up with a different algorithm.

Comment: Hi. May be, my eclipse is not using much of my computer memory, is there a way to increase its memory allocation, since my computer has 8GB RAM and 1TB hard disk.

Comment: Are you running from inside Eclipse? Try running your script directly from the command line...