# List comparison to return header value of different elements in python

Tags: python

This is related to [Element by element comparison in tuple to return set of sets - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635513/element-by-element-comparison-in-tuple-to-return-set-of-sets-python).

Since my nested loops were not efficient, I tried the suggestions given in that post.I used the below code,

```
seen=set()
def pairs(LoT):
    while LoT:
        f=LoT.pop(0)
        for e in LoT:
            se=frozenset([f, e])
            if se not in seen:
                seen.add(se)
                yield se


m = [[list_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]] for pair in pairs(rows)]

skt = set(frozenset(temp) for temp in m)
```

But, I am stuck with memory error while using this approach, Could someone help me in this.

```
    skt = set(frozenset([list_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]]) for pair in pairs(rows))
  File "C:*******Rough.py", line 139, in pairs
    seen.add(se)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Why do you have `seen` defined as a global *outside* of `pairs()`? How large is your data set? How often did you call `pairs()`?

Comment: Hi. My dataset has 50k records and each record has 15 elements. Since i have 50k records and i want to compare each record with all other record, i will have 50k factorial pairs i guess. Then, seen is creating a set which i want as an output.

Comment: I think `seen` will have "only" 50k^2 records, but this might be enough to clog your memory. However, do you need `seen` at all? It seems your method of iteration would prevent any duplicate pairs anyway, except there are duplicate elements in the original list. Add an `else` to the `if` and see whether it's ever executed.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. Is there any other approach for my requirement which could be more efficient.?

Comment: Also, have you tried `itertools.combinations`? Also, you could make `m` a generator (`(...)` instead of `[...]`) and pass that to `set` below so you do not expand all the pairs before filtering out duplicates.

Comment: itertools.combinations will give me all the combinations of tuples. But how can i compare each elements then? And where to change that generator? Do you mean this? m = [(list_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]) for pair in pairs(rows)]

Comment: `itertools.combinations(rows, 2)` should do the same as `pairs(rows)`, but maybe in a more efficient way. Just do the same processing you do now to get your `m`. BTW, it would help if you explained what you are actually trying to achieve... Also, have you considered using `pairs(set(rows))` to prevent duplicate pairs in the first place?

Comment: Ok cool. Let me explain, I have a data set with attributes in the first row and the tuples in the remaining rows. I have to compare each tuple with other tuples and return the attribute name of the differing element. So my output should be set of sets. If you need an example on this, you can see the question i linked with this. thank you for your help.